# Как отсортировать массив по другому массиву?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Допустим у нас есть массив
 `[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:5}, {id:4}]` 
каким образом отсортировать порядок этого массива по ID, если у нас есть другой массив где определен порядок
  `[{id:5}, {id:2}, {id:4}, {id:1}]` 
как эталон например. ? Т.е. массив где надо отсортировать, и массив где указан эталонный порядок. Массивы именно в формате JSON, а не просто массив [число, ...]. Т.к. в массиве еще другие есть, но дело не в этом. Интересует получение именно порядка последовательностей которым будет являться эталон - второй массив.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отсортировать массив объектов по значеням второго массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382973/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведите второй массив к виду объекта, где ключами будут `id` а значениями - необходимые порядковые номера. А затем просто отсортируйте на основании значений данного объекта.

```js
var order = [ {id:5}, {id:1}, {id:2} ];
var data = [ {id:1,data : 1}, {id:2, data: 2}, {id:5, data: 3}];


var orderObj = order.reduce( (a,c,i) => { a[c.id] = i; return a; } , {});
data.sort( (l,r) =>  orderObj[l.id] - orderObj[r.id] );

console.log(data);
```